# CDF of Planck distribution

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

Density function of Planck distribution is of the form
$$
f(x|a, b) = \frac{b^{a+1}}{\Gamma(a+1) \zeta(a+1)} \frac{x^a}{e^{bx}-1}.
$$
Is there analytical solution for cumulative distribution function or any way to calculate it apart from straightforward numerical integration?

Comment: Nope. A convenient representation of $X$ with this PDF is that $$X=\frac Y{bN}$$ where $(N,Y)$ is independent, the distribution of $Y$ is standard gamma of parameter $a+1$, with PDF $$f_Y(y)=\frac1{\Gamma(a+1)}y^ae^{-y}$$ and $N$ is discrete zeta, with PMF $$P(N=n)=\frac1{n^{a+1}\zeta(a+1)}$$

Comment: Sorry to ask, but what are the restrictions on the constants $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @omegadot Both positive, of course.